# SpaceX CRS-11 landing smoke color is weird

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, landing, crs-10, crs-11

So a couple of minutes ago, the Falcon 9 of CRS-11 just landed and I noticed that the "smoke" color was a little different. It is more "red" compared to landings from other missions.

---

CRS-11 (weird color):

[image]

CRS-10:

[image]

NROL-76:[image]

---

Is it because of the new paint on LZ-1? What can be the cause of this?

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that it's just simply dust. Florida right now is in somewhat of a drought at the moment and this could cause dry dust to settle on the landing pad. After the Static-fire test of CRS-11 there was a brush fire that had started (demonstrating the dryness in Florida). As for the specific color of the dust, it looks as if the top picture has somewhat of a filter on it which may be contributing to this certain color of the dust. Different times of day may also have affects on the color of it. As launches in the morning (at least where I live) such as NROL-76 and CRS-10 both had lighter colors of smoke/dust, than the evening launch of CRS-11. So unless SpaceX is testing some experimental Nitrogen Tetroxide engines (*joke) It should just be benign dust.

Comment: Good point about time but for the filter part, I checked other footage of the landing and they were all red-ish.

Comment: Not sure why you're referring to California. The static-fire test and the launch both happened in Florida, on pad 39A.

Comment: @Deimophobia not sure why I put California either. Just fixed.

Comment: Could it be this stuff getting kicked up, used preventatively? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phos-Chek

Comment: @uhoh that's a possibility, the Phos-chek on the wiki page looks more reddish but they could have different formulations with different colors

Comment: I wonder if it can have something in common with boiling oil from the hydraulic system. F9 doesn't recirculate oil used in hydraulic actuators (legs, valves, etc) but dumps it into fuel tank; if they changed the oil type it could have such results.

Answer (score 3):

In this launch, LZ-1 was covered with new radio-reflective paint to assist more precise landing. I think the paint could be the source of this red smoke.

Source: https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/871228411494014976